# Gamma decay multipolar transition rate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

I have been trying to derive the equation for the transition probability per unit time/transition rate for gamma decay of a nucleus, as given by equation (21) of [this article](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOnYf0r-PMAhULQY8KHYJlBlwQFggyMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F0908.4307&usg=AFQjCNGwsB1siapE2zx61Pl6LD7fvFe88g&sig2=5QfKTpqRlEB5n77JFEOEmQ).
I have also gone through several books about time dependent perturbation treatment of such transitions but none discuss the derivation of this result. Could anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how formal and rigorous you are hoping to be, but I think the most intuitive derivation of this equation I have seen is to start with the classical electrodynamics expression for the power radiated from an electric/magnetic multipole source. Then you quantize by interpreting power (Energy / time) as (Energy / photon) * (photons / time). The energy per photon is $\hbar\omega$ and so if you divide the formula for power by $\hbar\omega$ you get the probability per unit time to emit a photon, i.e. the decay rate.
If you want to see the derivation of the classical electromagnetic formula, you should consult a standard text book.